# Error while installing ruby ruby-1.9.3-p551

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, osx-yosemite, ruby-1.9.3

While installing ruby version 1.9.3-p551 i get the following error.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p551 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /Users/brijesh/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551 - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /Users/brijesh/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/brijesh/.rvm/log/1449735140_ruby-1.9.3-p551/make.log
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/brijesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend
    SOLIBS =
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling dmyversion.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
{standard input}:24852:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
make: *** [array.o] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

One of the project i am working on says it needs this version of ruby but i am getting this error.

I have searched all over the internet and found solutions like

```
rvm get stable/head/master
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967723/error-while-installing-ruby-1-9-3).

but the result is the same.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14072970/5515449